# Set Outlook MailItem as read or suppress_receipt in PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS

Tags: outlook, mapi

What's the proper way to set a MailItem as read before opening or set the value suppress_receipt in PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS?

Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815395(v=office.12).aspx my code is:

```
MailItem x = item as MailItem;
x.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E070003",35);
```

I got 35 from other read mails using OutlookSpy, assuming it contains the boolean flag for "Read".

Running this code gets me the exception "The operation failed". 
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that in the Outlook Object Model. On the MAPI level, you need to call `IMessage::SetReadFlag(SUPPRESS_RECEIPT)`, but you will need C++ or Delphi for that.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) is an option, you can use [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`MarkRead(SuppressReceipt)` (can be called from any language)

Comment: Using redemption worked perfectly.
It opened fine, however, when I close the inspector Outlook crashes.

rdo.RDOSession session = new rdo.RDOSession();
                        MailItem x = item as MailItem;
                        session.MAPIOBJECT = Globals.ThisAddin.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;

rdo.RDOMail m = session.GetMessageFromMsgFile(path,false);
m.MarkRead(true);       
m.Display(false,"");

Comment: m.Display("","") crashed on me. I ended up saving the mail to disk and opening again as MailItem to display

Comment: Display takes Boolean as a parameter, not a string. Do you mean crash as in "access violation" or a "COM error"?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
string PR_CLIENT_READ = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E070003";                            omMailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(PR_CLIENT_READ, 0x09);
```

Comment: The property is called PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS, not PR_CLIENT_READ. You cannot and should not directly set that property. Some store providers will not let you do that.